Github Action not failing when cloudformation deploy fails
I am updating AWS Cloudformation stacks using a Github Action.
In this process I am updating multiple cloudformation stacks in a single Github Action. This has been working fine for quite some time.
However, sometimes one of my stacks fail to update. When this happens the Github Action still reports success:

Again this happened here:

It appears that the Github Action will only return a failure if the last stack that was being updated failed. If there are actions after the failure it continues without error.
Here is an example of one of the Github Action:
jobs:
  DeployToDev:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Git Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '20'
      - name: Install AWS CLI
        run: |
          if [[ ! -d "./aws" ]]
          then
            curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
            unzip -qq awscliv2.zip
            sudo ./aws/install --update
          fi
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@master
        with:
          role-to-assume: ${{ env.AWS_ROLE_TO_ASSUME }}
          aws-region: us-east-1
      - name: Build
        run: infrastructure/build.sh
      - name: Deploy
        run: infrastructure/deploy.sh

The problem I am running into is the Deploy step, that is where I have my AWS deploys. Here is a snippet from the deploy.sh file. Note there are multiple aws deploys happening here, but if any were to fail I want the entire action to fail.
aws cloudformation deploy \
    --stack-name test-${ENVIRONMENT} \
    --template-file src/events/test/infrastructure.yml \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM \
    --no-fail-on-empty-changeset

aws cloudformation deploy \
    --stack-name test1-${ENVIRONMENT} \
    --template-file src/events/test1/infrastructure.yml \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM \
    --no-fail-on-empty-changeset


I believe this will answer the question: Aborting a shell script if any command returns a non-zero value.

Yup that does the trick, thank you!
